# Git moving files I never moved

Tags: git

I wanted to gain more experience in git so I decided to do some experimenting on my own.

I basically wanted to see the different behavior between merging and rebasing when it came to moving/deleting/editing files.

So I created a file structure likes this:

```
├── a
│   ├a.txt
│   ├aa.txt
├── b
│   ├b.txt
│   ├bb.txt
├── c
│   ├c.txt
│   ├cc.txt
```

The contents of each `.txt` is simply the name of the file.
Then I made three branches

```
MoveATXT
DeleteATXT
EditATXT
```

In each I respectively moved/deleted/edited the file `a.txt` that resided in /a
For moving I moved `/a/a.txt` to `/b/a.txt`
All moving/deleting was done by git commands `git rm` `git mv`

The behavior of `git merge` was what I had expected and understood.
It was `git rebase` that made me very confused.

When I made a new branch `BranchOne` I decided to first `git rebase MoveATXT` which went fine and the move appeared. Next I decided to `git rebase DeleteATXT` this is where things got weird for me.

It first gave me a printout of what was wrong. It was pretty much what I had expected to happen.

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Move a.txt to b/
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A       a/a.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (rename/delete): a/a.txt deleted in HEAD and renamed to b/a.txt in Move a.txt to b/. Version Move a.txt to b/ of b/a.txt left in tree.
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Move a.txt to b/
Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

However when I did a `git status`

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 7a2c06d
You are currently rebasing branch 'test' on '7a2c06d'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    a/aa.txt -> b/aa.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        added by them:   b/a.txt
```

It informs me that `a/aa.txt` had been moved to `b/aa.txt`

Further more when I `ls` it showed me that `a/` was missing

```
$ ls
b/  c/
```

When I check `b/` It does have both `a.txt` `aa.txt

```
$ ls b/
a.txt  aa.txt  b.txt  bb.txt
```

Why does this happen? I never moved `a/aa.txt` why is git moving it for me? How come the `a/` directory was deleted?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior. I don't mean this as a slight, but given the number of times `rebase` has been used without such unexplained file movement, it's more likely an observation error in the experiment.  If you're convinced otherwise, then please re-run the test while logging the exact commands and output.